# UITableview Auto Adjust Row Issue Swift IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, row-height

I am facing one issue with adjusting `UITableView` row hight dynamically. I know by using this methods we can achieve

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

but in my case I am using `XIB` file for `UITableViewCell` and I am adding shadow for cells. in this case how to add row height dynamically. At the same time, based on server time I am showing and hiding buttons. So please can anyone suggest me how to fix this issue. This is my cell for row index method.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "Custom"
        var cell: PApplyLeaveTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? PApplyLeaveTableViewCell
        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PApplyLeaveTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? PApplyLeaveTableViewCell
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        var localDic :NSDictionary!
        localDic = totlLeavesArray.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        cell.acknowled_lbl.text = localDic["acknowledgement"] as? String
        cell.date_lbl.text = localDic["totalDate"] as? String
        cell.reason_lbl.text = localDic["reason"] as? String
        let compareDate = localDic["compare"] as? String
        if(compareDate == "No")
        {
            cell.delet_Btn.isHidden = true
            cell.edit_Btn.isHidden = true
        }
        else
        {
            cell.delet_Btn.isHidden = false
            cell.edit_Btn.isHidden = false
        }
        cell.edit_Btn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.edit_Btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PApplyLeaveViewController.EditViewAction(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)
        cell.delet_Btn.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.delet_Btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PApplyLeaveViewController.DeleteAction(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)
        let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 8, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 15, height: 220))
        whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9])
        whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
        cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved my issue by setting  constraints  values. i taken label bottom constraint to "bottom space to container". This is my code for handling buttons show and hidden. But i couldn't able to fix row height accordingly. but somehow i am fixing  design problem.

```
if compareDateString == currentDateString
        {
            cell.delete_Btn.isHidden = true
            cell.edit_Btn.isHidden = true
            cell.bottomConstraint.constant = 30
        }

        else if compareDateString! < currentDateString
        {
            cell.delete_Btn.isHidden = true
            cell.edit_Btn.isHidden = true
          cell.bottomConstraint.constant = 30
        }
        else
        {
            cell.delete_Btn.isHidden = false
            cell.edit_Btn.isHidden = false
            cell.bottomConstraint.constant = 45

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your label frame by AutoLayout contraints then Build and run

Answer (score 0):

So I assume the issue here is that the cells stay at their estimated height of 44 points.  The problem you have is that although the sub views of the cell may change there is nothing relating that back to the cell frame size itself.  For example you make the whiteRoundedView a certain size but how is that going to affect the size of the cell itself.

There are two basic ways to handle this situation:

1) Instead of using a dynamic height for the cells use this method to determine the height of each cell based on the app state

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

2) Switch to using auto-layout and setup constraints to relate the cell size to its contents.

One other point that will come back to bite you eventually and that is that you are adding a whiteRoundedView each time the system wants the cell which includes when an existing one is dequeued.  A dequeued cell will already have had a whiteRoundedView added when it was created.  You really want to move that code into where you create the cell like this:

```
if cell == nil {
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PApplyLeaveTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? PApplyLeaveTableViewCell

    let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 8, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 15, height: 220))
    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9])
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
    cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

so that it is only added once.

In fact if you are using a XIB why not setup the shadow view in that and then just tweak the parameters.

Comment: first of all thank you replying me. let me try your suggestions.

Comment: for example i am taking one uiview inside that uitableviewcell background view for labels and buttons. i will set shadow for that view upto here everything is going fine . but in my case buttons will appear sometimes and will hide sometimes that time how to adjust row height

Comment: As I say in my answer you can either use method 1 and specify the row heights directly in the delegate or 2 use auto layout and set constraints on everything to tie the views to the cell to allow it to determine it's height.

Comment: in your first option if i set row statically how come it will adjust row height dynamically with row data

Comment: In order to get a UITableView to adjust row heights dynamically you really need to be using auto layout and setting up the appropriate constraints.  Now if you don't understand how that works you need to check out the documentation and find some tutorials as it's to big of a topic to explain here.  My first option involves abandoning the use of letting the UITableView and cells adjust the heights automatically and to get the delegate to specify them.

Comment: i am adding constraints accordingly but no result.

Comment: You should update the original question with how you have setup the constraints

Comment: in tableview cell for each label i have to set constraints right

Comment: But how have you set them.  Have you provided enough constraints that the cell can work out its size correctly?

Comment: Sorry due to overload of  work couldn't able to answer here. i resolved my issue. i am going to post my answer please let me know wether i am right or wrong. but problem got resolved with that answer.